# How to send job status in Oozie Mail?

Tags: shell, email, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am creating a oozie workflow, where it has to trigger an automatic mail once the job is completed with the details of the job and the job status.

In short, I need the ouput of this command ---> **oozie job -oozie {SERVER_DETAILS} -info ${job_id}** in the oozie mail to be sent via mail.

When I try this,

```
<action name="an-email"> 
<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
<to></to> <cc></cc> 
<subject>Email notifications for ${wf:id()}</subject> 
<body>The wf ${wf:id()} successfully completed.</body> </email> 
<ok to="myotherjob"/> 
<error to="errorcleanup"/> 
</action>
```

I am just able to mail the job id alone, but I need to include the job status and execution time.

Comment: Ahem. Since the "email" Action runs inside the Workflow, you can be pretty sure that the Workflow status is RUNNING and the execution stop time is still undefined; so what is the point in displaying the status?!

Comment: A dirty workaround could be a Shell action taking as args *(1)* the Oozie URL *(2)* the Workflow ID *(3)* the Workflow name *(4)* the [list of] e-mail address, and running sthg like `oozie job -oozie "$1" -info "$2" | mailx  -s "Execution report from $3 : success" "$4"` (assuming that all YARN nodes can send Ops e-mails via `mailx`)

Answer (score 0):

Oozie does not have EL function for status like for id `wf:id()`, which you are using. What you can do is, define two email actions, one for Failure and another for Success and send the customized message as per your need. That will solve the issue for you.

[Expression Language Functions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions)